# SQL index for SELECT FROM table t JOIN

Tags: sql, join, indexing

Haven't played with SQL in a while.

What would be the best index for:

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM My_Table x 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT id, MAX(update_time) AS last_update  
     FROM My_Table 
     GROUP BY name) y ON x.name = y.name 
                      AND x.score 
                      AND x.update_time = y.last_update)
```

The query might not make sense...but for the sake of it.

```
ALTER TABLE My_Table ADD INDEX my_index(name, surname, update_time) ??
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE My_Table ADD INDEX my_index(update_time, name, surname) ??
```

Also, there are queries based on name, surname

Comment: What's the database? You can have a much better optimization in PostgreSQL.

Comment: MySQL database .

Answer (score 1):

First, write the query as:

```
SELECT x.*, 
FROM (SELECT x.*, MAX(update_time) OVER (PARTITION BY name, score ORDER BY update_time DESC) as last_update
      FROM my_table x
     ) x
WHERE update_time = last_update;
```

And use the index `(name, score, update_time desc)`.

With the same query, you can use:

```
select x.*
from my_table x
where x.update_time = (select max(x2.update_time)
                       from my_table x2
                       where x2.name = x.name and x2.score = x.score
                      );
```

This often has the best performance (with the right index) on many databases.

Comment: Nice. How will this perform under 100K+  of rows?

Comment: @UnguruBulan . . . With the right indexes, it should be quite fast.